# Numbering lines matching the pattern using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I'm writing the script that searches for lines that match some pattern. I must use sed for this script.
This works fine for searching and printing matched lines:

```
sed -n /PATTERN/p
```

However, I'd also like to print the matched lines number in front of the line itself.
How can I do that using sed?

Comment: Do you want them numbered consecutively or based on their line number within the file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -n pattern file
```

If you use `=` in `sed` the line number will be printed on a separate line and is not available in the pattern space for manipulation. However, you can pipe the output into another instance of sed to merge the line number and the line it applies to.

GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/pattern/{=;p}' file | sed '{N;s/\n/ /}'
```

MacOS `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/pattern/{=' -e 'p' -e '}' file | sed -e '{N' -e 's/\n/ /' -e '}'
```

Comment: what does 
```sed '{N;s/\n/ /}' ```do?

please explain

Comment: @frpfarhan: It puts the line of output on the same line as its line number. `N` appends the next line to the one currently in the pattern space. `s/\n/ /` changes the newline between the two lines into a space. The curly braces in the (second) `sed` command aren't really necessary.

Answer (score 13):

`=` is used to print the line number.

```
sed -n /PATTERN/{=;p;}
```

Comment: i do this: cat "$FILE" | sed -n /"$pattern"/{=;p;} , but i get error: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Comment: @zum: Move your quotes so they're outside the script: `sed -n "/$pattern/{=;p;}" "$FILE"`

Answer (score 11):

For sed, use following to get line number

```
sed -n /PATTERN/=
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch to awk.

```
BEGIN {
  ln=0
}

$0 ~ m {
  ln+=1
  print ln " " $0
  next
}

{
  print $0
}
```

...

```
awk -f script.awk -v m='<regex>' < input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print "$.: $_" if /regex/' input.file
```

`$.` contain line number. If input file contains:

```
record foo
bar baz
record qux
```

This one-liner: `perl -ne 'print "$.: $_" if /record/' input.file` will print:

```
1: record foo
3: record qux
```

Or if you just want total number of lines matched a pattern use:

`perl -lne '$count++ if /regex/; END { print int $count }' input.file`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way:

```
awk '{print ln++  ":  "  $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I am showing a simpler sed program (to be executed with `sed -f` (and srciptfilename). This is a sed-program that can increment an input number:

```
s/$/_/; # mimick an external carry to trigger incrementation

# Looping the carry till there is anything to carry:
:carry
/_/ {
    s/0_/10/;
    s/1_/20/;
    s/2_/30/;
    s/3_/40/;
    s/4_/50/;
    s/5_/60/;
    s/6_/70/;
    s/7_/80/;
    s/8_/90/;
    s/9_/_0/;

    s/^_/10/;

    b carry;
}

s/0$//; # remove the effect of the initial external carry
```

With this, we can write a sed program that can emumerate things.
For example, a sed program that enumerates all lines (without exception):

```
# Increment the state:
x; # swap to access state
    s/$/_/; # mimick an external carry to trigger incrementation

        # Looping the carry:
        :carry
        /_/ {
            s/0_/10/;
            s/1_/20/;
            s/2_/30/;
            s/3_/40/;
            s/4_/50/;
            s/5_/60/;
            s/6_/70/;
            s/7_/80/;
            s/8_/90/;
            s/9_/_0/;

            s/^_/10/;

            b carry;
        }

    s/0$//; # remove the effect of the initial external carry

x; # swap back from state

# Get the state and use it for representing enumeration:
G;
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\t\1/;
```

Now the idea is clear. With these principles, we can enumerate special lines, too. Fore example, here is a sed program that enumerates empty lines only:

```
/^$/ {
    x;
        s/$/_/;

            :carry
            /_/ {
                s/0_/10/;
                s/1_/20/;
                s/2_/30/;
                s/3_/40/;
                s/4_/50/;
                s/5_/60/;
                s/6_/70/;
                s/7_/80/;
                s/8_/90/;
                s/9_/_0/;

                s/^_/10/;

                b carry;
            }

        s/0$//;
    x;
    g;
}
```