# Insert line numbers into file with sed

Tags: sed

I am learning how to use sed, and saw that I can use the `=` to insert line numbers. However, this includes a newline:

file:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
```

running `sed -n '=;p' file`:

```
1
alpha
2
beta
3
gamma
```

Is it possible, in a single call to sed, to insert these line numbers *on the same line*? So:

```
1 alpha
2 beta
3 gamma
```

I know that it is possible to do this with other tools, but I am wondering about the specific functionality of sed. Is there a way to append perhaps another regular-expression substitution after the `=` to remove newlines?

Comment: Why `sed`? `awk -v ln=1 '{print ln++  " "  $0 }' file`

Comment: I know, but wondering if it's possible otherwise. However Im willing to be convinced awk is better...

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/cat-_002dn.html#cat-_002dn

Comment: the `=` command actually prints the line number, it does not insert it into the pattern space. `sed = file | paste - -` is a goofy way to write `nl file`

Comment: Not sure `sed` is that easy as `awk` [here](https://ideone.com/YHC3Ze).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbering lines matching the pattern using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577256/numbering-lines-matching-the-pattern-using-sed)

Comment: [This](http://tpcg.io/P1FC3t) works but is a cheat, better off using `cat -n file`

Answer (score 12):

This would be work for you.

```
sed '=' file | sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: It seems that there are two sed calls in my answer. :)

Comment: Can you give an explanation, what is doing here?

Comment: @YuJiaao Just print the file with line number at the beginning of each line. :)

Comment: Wonderful! Do you happen to know how to pad the number with a leading 0 if necessary?

Comment: @Xerus I'm afraid I can't do this with **sed**. But a workaround could be `awk '{printf("%0.2d %s\n", NR, $0)}' your_file_name`

Comment: Thanks, that does look nicer :)
I solved it by inserting this: `sed '=' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]$/0\0/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
Both orders: 

echo -e "Jan J.\nKarel K.\nPetr P." |sed -rn "=;p;"|  sed -r "N;s/\n/ /;"
 1 Jan J.
 2 Karel K.
 3 Petr P.

echo -e "Jan J.\nKarel K.\nPetr P." |sed -rn "p;=;"|  sed -r "N;s/\n/ /;"
 Jan J. 1
 Karel K. 2
 Petr P. 3

echo -e "Jan J.\nKarel K.\nPetr P." |sed -rn "=;p;" |  sed -r "N;s/\n/ /;" | sed -r 's/^([0-9]*) (.*) (.*)$/\2 \1 \3/'
 Jan 1 J.
 Karel 2 K.
 Petr 3 P.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice thing in a cheat sheet https://quickref.me/sed.html (I didn't write it).

Number line of a file (simple left alignment)

```
$ sed = file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'
```

Number line of a file (number on left, right-aligned)

```
$ sed = file.txt | sed 'N; s/^/   /; s/ *\(.\{6,\}\)\n/\1  /'
```

Number line of file, but only print numbers if line is not blank

```
$ sed '/./=' file.txt | sed '/./N; s/\n/ /'
```

Count lines (emulates "wc -l")

```
$ sed -n '$='
```